# peewee installer for windows

Tags: python, peewee

I'm trying to install peewee on windows machine.
Is there an installer for windows?
or installation instructions for windows?
I'm new to Python/peewee and cant seem to find any.

Comment: Have you trying installing it with python? ->
http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/installation.html

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.
I've learnt that I need to install pip first as per:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows
than from windows command line run:
pip install peewee

Answer (score 3):

There is no standalone installer for peewee that i know .  but you can install peewee **using pip** easily .

this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows) gives detailed instructions on **installing pip on windows**.

afters setting up pip, you can install peewee by using command in cmd

```
pip install peewee
```